# Join em sql que retorna tudo

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tenho duas tabelas, a de episódios e de episódios vistos, preciso fazer uma consulta que vai juntar as duas pelo id do episodio, porem eu não quero que os episódios que não estão na segunda tabela não venham no resultado, vou tentar dar um exemplo:

[image: Primeira tabela]
Essa é a primeira tabela

[image: Segunda tabela]
Essa é a segunda tabela

[image: resultado]
Juntando as duas quero que de isso

Se tiver ficado alguma dúvida, me perguntem por favor.
Obrigado

Comment: Você quer uma junção à esquerda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem varias formar de fazer junções, no seu caso você tem que fazer uma junção a esquerda, que só considera os registros de um lado da tabela caso não exista do outro, abaixo uma imagem ilustrativa para ficar melhor explicado com exemplos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: nada :), precisando tamos ae